# session_start headers already sent

Tags: session, header

I got a problem that I can't solve despite searching for answer.
It's the code of the index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Elektromechanika Pojazdowa</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body bgcolor="#170266">
    <center>
        <div id="naglowek">ELEKTROMECHANIKA POJAZDOWA</div>
        <div id="menu">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <a class="menu" href="index.php?p=main">Strona Główna</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <a class="menu" href="index.php?p=contact">Kontakt</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </center>
    <?php
        $p = $_GET['p'];
        if(!empty($p))
        include("$p".'.php');
        else
        include('main.php');
    ?>
    <div id="stopka">
        <center>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">
            <center><img src="img/bendiks.jpg"></center>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%">
            <center><img src="img/magneti marelli.jpg" width="300px"     height="170px"></center>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%">
            <center><img src="img/bosch.jpeg"></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div id="link">
        <a class="admin" href="index.php?p=admin">Panel adminitracyjny</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

I can't get it to work, because I get error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - 
headers already sent by (output started at D:\Program Files\WebServ\httpd-users\dla 
Gabi\index.php:1) in D:\Program Files\WebServ\httpd-users\dla Gabi\index.php on line 2
```

I tried using `ob_start();` but it just doesn't work. I don't understand why there is a problem, cause `session_start();` is the first function, placed even before any html code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Do you see **Related** column on the right?

Comment: I looked for answer in related topic but didn't find help :( I have to save file in UTF-8 encoding and it's the probable problem.. So is there any way to save the file in UTF-8 encoding and erease this problem?

Comment: Ok, I figured out that I need to hexedit the file after every saving and delete first 3 invisible digits.. But is there any way to do it permanently?

Comment: @ArkadiuszGaller use another text editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enable ob_start in php.ini file
<?php
session_start();
ini_set("ob_start","On");

?>
```

Comment: I can do it on my own PC, but on the external hosting it's unfortunately not possible :(
If you mean doing it in the file index.php (just as you wrote) - it doesn't work, ob_start is ignored by this error

Comment: In php.ini find ob_start and if ob_start off means you will on

Comment: but i can't get to php.ini on the external hosting server, that's the problem

Comment: ok. ob_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 0):

To get to the php.ini on the external hosting server, I think you need to set up a Virtual Private Server (VPS). At least from the problems I myself encountered with the lack of a custom php.ini file on our hosting server, we needed a VPS in order to use our own ini files for the php protocol.